# How to find missing elements from two data frames

Tags: r

I have two dataframes. The first is a set of addresses including City and State.  The second is from the zipcode package.   I am attempting to find all of the rows from the first data frame that have an invalid state and zipcode match.

I attempted to merge the two data frames together.  I was successful and can determine which ones match, but I really need to go the other direction and find the errors

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please make this question *reproducible*. This includes sample code (including listing non-base R packages), sample data (e.g., `dput(head(x))`), and expected output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: `anti_join` from the `dplyr` package?

Answer (score 1):

**Credits go to @ericOss, anti_join is the easiest way**

---

**Sample data** 
*Next time either provide your data (or build a small example set as I did):*

```
library(zipcode)
data(zipcode)

# Data
df1 <- head(zipcode)
df2  <- head(zipcode)

# Remove some things
df2[2,1] <- 0000   #wrong zip
df2[4,3] <- 'FOO' # wrong stat
```

df1

```
    zip       city state latitude longitude
1 00210 Portsmouth    NH  43.0059  -71.0132
2 00211 Portsmouth    NH  43.0059  -71.0132
3 00212 Portsmouth    NH  43.0059  -71.0132
4 00213 Portsmouth    NH  43.0059  -71.0132
5 00214 Portsmouth    NH  43.0059  -71.0132
6 00215 Portsmouth    NH  43.0059  -71.0132
```

df2

```
   zip       city state latitude longitude
1 00210 Portsmouth    NH  43.0059  -71.0132
2     0 Portsmouth    NH  43.0059  -71.0132
3 00212 Portsmouth    NH  43.0059  -71.0132
4 00213 Portsmouth   FOO  43.0059  -71.0132
5 00214 Portsmouth    NH  43.0059  -71.0132
6 00215 Portsmouth    NH  43.0059  -71.0132
```

**Anti_join** 
Then you can use `print(df2 %>% anti_join(df1))` which will give you:

```
    zip       city state latitude longitude
1     0 Portsmouth    NH  43.0059  -71.0132
2 00213 Portsmouth   FOO  43.0059  -71.0132
```

> anti_join() return all rows from x where there are not matching values
>   in y, keeping just columns from x.

(anti_join comes with `dplyr` install it using `install.packages("dplyr")` if you haven't already)